# Standard ML (using MoscowML) Whats wrong with this function? (filter)

Tags: filter, sml, ml

This is part of a homework assignment so my goal is to understand **why** this is wrong. As I mentioned before I'm using Moscow ML.

```
fun filter pred = let
 fun f ([], a) = []
 | f ([], a) = a
 |   f (e::L, a) = if pred e then (f L (e::a) ) else (f L a)

in
 f
end
```

The error I get is:

```
| f (e::L, a) = if pred e then (f L (e::a) ) else (f L a)
                                  ^
Type clash: expression of type 
'a list cannot have type
'a list * 'b list
```

I have been reading up on documentation, and it really hasn't helped. What I really don't get is where 'b list is coming from. In our assignment we have to use an accumulator with tail recursion. I believe where my error is is how filter calls the function f. Filter takes the predicate as an argument and f should take the list and accumulator which is initially the empty list.

I've tried calling f like: f L [], But in other examples we didn't actually have to call f with its argument and it was somehow passed automatically.

Anyway, any help understanding where my mistake is and guidance on how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated.

-aitee

(also if anyone could give me any tips on decoding the type expression errors that could also be very beneficial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(f L (e::a))` would work only if `f` were a curried function, of type `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`. You should be doing:

```
if pred e then (f (L, (e::a))) else (f (L,a))
```

Btw., SMLNJ complains of a redundant match (two `f ([], a)` clauses are given).

Comment: Okay, I understand. What about:

Comment: in
f
end

I don't pass anything to f? How does that actually work? (the flow of the function inside a funtion.)

Comment: If this is a helpful answer, please click the accept button (the checkmark) and post any unrelated issues as separate questions. (A hint though: you're returning a function.)

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing tupled versus curried function calls.  Your definition of `f` demands a tuple, (a,b), but you're passing it arguments as `f a b`.  Try replacing your recursive calls to `f L ...` with `f (L,...)` instead.

The type error is a little unhelpful, but it's basically saying that you're passing a list when it expects a 2-tuple of lists.